# Is it possible for changing HTML 5 Datalist autocomplete behavior?

Tags: html, autocomplete, datalist

have a question: I'm using a lot of combination of input-datalist in my project for its autocomplete feature. But one thing that annoys me is that the autocomplete is always "left-oriented". 
i.e: if you have [apple, banana, orange] in options and you type "pp" it will not detected.

what I need is something like SQLs like '%keyword%'.

I see that JQueryUI autocomplete provides what I need:
[Changing HTML datalist autocomplete behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15210753/changing-html-datalist-autocomplete-behavior)

But I would like to avoid using external library if possible. Any suggestions?
Thanks before!

Answer (score 0):

Each browser implements this feature differently.

Firefox will match "apple" if you type "pp", because it matches elements containing "pp" as a substring.

Other browsers will only match elements that start with "pp".

See this: [html datalist element auto suggest behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27762693/html-datalist-element-auto-suggest-behavior)