# html datalist element auto suggest behavior

Tags: html, cross-browser, html-datalist

I noticed that different browsers have different behavior regarding to suggesting values for a text field when you hook it up to a datalist. Some browsers show the entries which exactly *starts with* what you've typed(IE, older chrome versions), while others show entries which *contain* what you've typed as a sub-string (firefox, newer chrome versions).

For example, type `i` into the text box, and observe the suggestions:

```html
browser: 
<datalist id="browsers">
    <option value="Google Chrome">Google Chrome</option>
    <option value="Internet Explorer">Internet Explorer</option>
    <option value="Firefox">Firefox</option>
    <option value="Opera">Opera</option>
    <option value="Safari">Safari</option>
    <option value="Others">Others?</option>
</datalist>
 <input type="text" name="browser" list="browsers">
```

(or here's a fiddle, if you prefer http://jsfiddle.net/yaj8ut3m/ )

In IE, it will suggest only `Internet Explorer`, but firefox & recent chrome will suggest `Internet Explorer`, `Firefox`, and `Safari`.

**Is there some way to specify which auto suggest filtering behavior to use?**

note: javascript solutions aren't acceptable

Comment: I think, there is no way to change this behavior, because every browser has different implementation. I can't find any regulations in standards for suggestions.

Comment: @zoonman ya I can't find anything in the specs either. This is really unfortunate, because I feel like the lack of configuration will really limit how many people make use of this feature.

Comment: "javascript solutions aren't acceptable".... this isn't even a serious question. It's either a theroetical exercise or a standards feature request posed as a question to seemingly raise awareness. I have an excercise for you - name a user-agent that implements this html5 feature and doesn't support javascript.. then go ahead and consider all the user-agents that support javascript without implementing this html5 feature..

Comment: Since august 2016, chrome also uses "contains" instead of "starts with". (https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=153991). Better late than never.

Answer (score 4):

This is [unspecified](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/forms.html#the-datalist-element) option.

And known [issue](http://www.wufoo.com/html5/elements/5-datalist.html):

```
If you type "V" the list will show only items that start with "V" in Chrome, Opera and IE, and any <option> containing "V" in Firefox.
```

Answer (score 2):

If the question is:

"Is there some way to specify which auto suggest filtering behavior to use?

note: javascript solutions aren't acceptable"

the answer will (sadly) be: No there isn't, this depend on browser's implementation and the datalist tag hasn't any attribute.

I have to say that is full of "plugins" and is relatively simply to write one but using js.