# Datalist differences Chrome vs Firefox (space behaviour)

Tags: html

I have an issue when using datalist :

I have a datalist with some values :

- ABC
- A B C
- A BC
- CBA
- C B A

In Firefox : when i type in the input "A B C" it's working in the way i want it will filter the datalist to put only the result "A B C", it seems to do a search like contains : "A" AND "space" AND "B" AND "space" and "C"

But in Chrome / Edge : for the same search it will output all the results,  it seems to do a search like contains : "A" OR "B" OR "C".

**Is there a way to change the chrome and edge behaviour to work like in the Firefox Browser (HTML or JS) ?**

You can run the snippest below (the behaviour is different according to your current browser),

```html
<input list='datalist'type='text'>
<datalist id='datalist'>
  <option value="ABC">ABC</option>
  <option value="A B C">A B C</option>
  <option value="A BC">A BC</option>
  <option value="AB C">AB C</option>
  <option value="C B A">C B A</option>
  <option value="CBA">CBA</option>
</datalist>
```

Comment: No, I don't think you can influence that using HTML/JS. This behavior is really up to the browser.

Comment: Unlucky, So I have no choice to do my custom datalist

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/27762693/1427878 from 2015 comes to the same conclusion, I don't think anything relevant in this regard has changed since then.

Comment: Only `option` elements that are not `disabled` are valid suggestions, so you _could_ try and add an `input` event handler to your input field, and then "filter" the valid options yourself based on that (i.e., toggle their `disabled` property accordingly) ... But I am not sure how nicely the browsers will play along with such "dynamic" updating when the suggestion list is already being shown, you'd have to test if that actually works. But if so, it could spare you from having to re-create the _whole_ functionality this offers, yourself.

Comment: Yeah i found some suggestion about it, with the event "on input" where i filter the items myself.